# Selenium XPATH not finding element

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to find an element with xpath but it is not working.

```
import string
import random

import os


from random_word import RandomWords

import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))

driver.get("https://yopmail.com/en/")
driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'login').send_keys('grudsimcobottest')
driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'login').submit()

try:
    elem = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[text()="Confirm account deletion"]'))
    )
finally:
    a = 1
    
confirm_email = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[text()="Confirm account deletion"]')
confirm_email.click


try:
    elem = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//a[text()="Delete"]'))
    )
finally:
    a = 1

delete_button_in_email = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//a[text()="Delete"]')
delete_button_in_email.click()
```

This is the code^

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\notgr\Desktop\Everything\SC ahks\python\yopmailmakendelete.py", line 28, in <module>
    elem = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(
  File "C:\Users\notgr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 90, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

This is the error^

[the website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/siqdt.png)

If you go to yopmail.com and type in grudsimcobottest you can see it live if you like. I'm not sure why the div highlighted isn't being selected and clicked, it times out when looking for it. Help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<iframe frameborder="0" width="100%" height="100%" src="" name="ifinbox" onload="onloadifinbox()" id="ifinbox" state="full"></iframe>
```

Your element is in an iframe switch to it prior to finding the element.

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.NAME,"ifinbox")))
```